# How to use a lower version of python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I have python 3.8, but need to develop a script in python 3.6. Can I create a virtual environment to work with that lower version of python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create the script in Python3.6 you first need to create a new environment with Python3.6

Depending on your OS, there are slightly different ways to create a virtual environment.

You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65818356/11588364).

Comment: If you feel that another Q&A appropriately addresses the question, please flag or vote it as a duplicate instead of repeating information.